# Using Case Statement in SQL with parameter/variable to check for Null values

Tags: sql, null, case, where-clause

I am trying to write a SQL Select statement to return records based on a user input through a front end. 
I want to write the Select statement like this:

```
SELECT somefields
FROM sometable
WHERE CASE variable
         WHEN 'blank' THEN field IS NULL
         ELSE field = field
      END
```

Basically I either want to filter a column to find NULL values or ignore the filter and return all values depending on the value of the variable. I know that the results of the CASE statement is not executable but how can I do this?

Comment: What version of SQL (mySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle?)

Answer (score 3):

When `variable` is 'blank', the following query will give you rows where `field` is NULL. When `variable` is anything else, it will give you all rows:

```
SELECT somefields
FROM sometable
WHERE
    (variable = 'blank' AND field IS NULL)
    OR (variable <> 'blank')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`NULLIF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) (link is for SQL Server, but `NULLIF()` should be standard):

```
SELECT somefields
  FROM sometable
 WHERE field = NULLIF(variable, 'blank')
```

Comment: This will make `field = variable`  if variable != 'blank'. OP requested `field = field` when variable is 'blank'

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet should behave as follows:

- when `@variable is null`, return all rows
- when `@variable = 'blank'`, return all rows where `field is null` or `field = 'blank'`
- otherwise, return rows where `@variable` equals `field`

Code snippet:

```
WHERE 1 = CASE
      WHEN @variable is null then 1
      WHEN @variable = 'blank' and field is null then 1
      WHEN @variable = field then 1
      END
```

Comment: This worked great thanks essentially creates an "Optional Parameter" for a query, awesome

Comment: A note:  if you are testing the contents of a varchar parameter you need to ensure your case order is right i.e: check for '' (empty string) first, then check for null then for equality e.g. FIELD1 = @someParam1

Comment: Thanks! you saved my day .. erm night :) This is a very nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT somefields
FROM sometable
WHERE ((variable IS NULL OR variable = 0) OR (variable = field))
```

WHERE Criteria is apply when variable have value
For Example:

```
DECLARE @CityName VARCHAR(50)
SET @CityName = NULL

SELECT CityName
FROM City
WHERE ((@CityName IS NULL ) OR (@CityName = CityName ))
```

When City is null then tables return all rows

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're after.  Something like this maybe?

```
SELECT field1,
    field2,
    CASE variable
        WHEN 'blank' THEN NULL
        ELSE field3
    END as field3
FROM sometable
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I understand what you mean....for example....

```
    SELECT 
          House, Postcode 
    from 
          SomeTable 
    where
          (House=isnull(@House,House) or (House is null and @House is null))
    and
          (Postcode=isnull(@Postcode,Postcode) or (Postcode is null and @Postcode is null))
```

First bit of the conditional where is to use the variable, when present (the isnull bit is to ignore the variable if it's null)

Second bit of the conditional where is in case your evaluative field is null also as effectively fields don't = null they are 'is null'.

Confused? Good. Works on what I'm doing though!

Comment: Welcome on SO. I do not comprehend your explanation that comes with your code. Would it be possible that you rework it a little? You can do that by editing your own post. :) That will make your answer way more valuable for the community!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on @Andomar answer above aimed at anyone testing an input varchar value, you need to test the parameter in the right order as per the example below:

```
FIELD1 = CASE
  WHEN @inputParameter = '' THEN FIELD1
  WHEN @inputParameter <> FIELD1 THEN NULL  -- if input is some text but does not match
  WHEN @inputParameter IS NULL THEN FIELD1
  WHEN @inputParameter != '' AND FIELD1 = @inputParameter THEN FIELD1
END
```

Hope this helps someone.