# How to get all non null rows using a parameter?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

[This SQL Server Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190114/using-case-statement-in-sql-with-parameter-variable-to-check-for-null-values/8190187#8190187) was quite helpful. I'm using PL/SQL on Oracle 11g.  I want cursor to accept both `v_parm1` and `v_parm2`.

Here's what I've done.

```
DECLARE 
v_parm1 varchar2(50) := 'TALC';
v_parm2 varchar2(50) := '*';

cursor cursor_with_parms(in_parm_list varchar2)
is 
with mohs_scale as
(select '1' as moh_val , 'TALC' as mineral from dual union all
 select '2' as moh_val , 'GYPS' as mineral from dual union all
 select '3' as moh_val , 'CALC' as mineral from dual union all
 select '4' as moh_val , 'FLUO' as mineral from dual) 
 select moh_val,
        mineral 
 from   mohs_scale
 where
   case  in_parm_list when '*' then  mineral is not null 
   else   mineral = in_parm_list
end;      

BEGIN
for rock in cursor_with_parms(v_parm1) loop
dbms_output.put_line(rock.moh_val || ' ' || rock.mineral);
end loop; 
END;
```

If I use `v_parm1` then return just 1-TALC.
If I use `v_parm2` then return all 4 rows.

**Question:** How can I write cursor to accept either `v_parm1` or `v_parm2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a WHERE clause like this:

```
 WHERE
       (in_parm_list = '*')
    OR (mineral = in_parm_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Ref cursor if you want to change the query dynamically.