# spring data jpa native query with dynamic column in select statement

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to select the column value based on user credentials.

If the user is admin then the column value can display, if not empty value has to be displayed for the particular column. Sample code pasted here, I can't control it from java end

```
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long>(){
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT order_number from view_order order by created_on desc")
    List<Object[]> findOrderNumber();

}
```

what my idea is, pass the column as 'order_number' if the user is admin.  If not pass it as empty string like ' '. I could not get the desired output. Any one tried to generate the dynamic native query in spring data jpa repository

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT (:order_number) from view_order order by created_on desc")
List<Object[]> findOrderNumber( @Param("order_number") String  order_number);
```

Comment: This is not going to work. You cannot parameterize the columns. Such logic is probably better handled elsewhere anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement for your use case.

something like shown below:

```
select 
  case usertype
  when 'Admin' then orderNumber
  else ''
  end as number
from orders
```

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. Can you describe your answer for the asked usecase.

Comment: @shankarsh15 This doesn't help me :(

Comment: This is your requirement correct : If the user is admin then the column value can display, if not empty value has to be displayed for the particular column.

Comment: I din't mention that order table has user type as a column. user type is not available in the table, I am receiving it from the API request.

Comment: Please check this post out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190114/using-case-statement-in-sql-with-parameter-variable-to-check-for-null-values

Comment: @shankarsh15 I want to select the column value as empty, I don't want to check whether the column has value or not.